# How to modify virtualenv to achieve the same effect as --system-site-packages?

Tags: python, virtualenv

How can a virtualenv be modified *after it is created* so as to achieve the same effect as creating it with `virtualenv --system-site-packages`?  In other words, how to enable accessing any systemwide installed packages in a virtualenv which was originally created with that access disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete or rename the file `/virtualenv_root/lib/python3.4/no-global-site-packages.txt`

OR

Add a symlink between `/virtualenv_root/lib/python3.4/site-packages/` and `/path/to/desired/site-packages/`

Here `virtualenv_root` is the name of your virtual environment.

Comment: You missed a `python` + version in the path after `lib/`.

Comment: Also, if there is a `site-packages/` folder already, you probably need to create the symlinks inside.